# Responding to changes wpf c# using a list

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

PropertyChanged

```
    public void  NotifyPropertyChanged(string a)   
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)  
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(a)); 
        }
    }
```

i dont quite understand what is going on in this line

this.PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(a));

i did understand all the above  but i cant understand how this line work and i ask if i need this for wpf application im using a list of object im following this tutorial

https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/

but maybe i can use other way

Comment: See also [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: In order to update the UI when elements are added to or removed from a collection, use ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T>.